# GP-E2 - device not found

Tags: canon, macintosh, gps

I've got a GP-E2 for my Canon 5DS-R and it works great, adds all the GPS data onto each image (though some locations are way off so need to change them), but I also used the GP-E2 for tracking my route, but when I go into map utility on my mac it says it can't find the device.

Any ideas what I need to do as I'm getting very frustrated with not being able to view all the data I've collected.

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, and I'm connecting the GP-e2 via a USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - I contacted canon and they gave me a (free of charge) link to the latest software - all working perfectly now.

Comment: What's that link?